# Android - How do I get the values from a time picker?

Tags: android

Going purely from this tutorial (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) I can easily display the picker, but no idea how to get the actual values from it.

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}`

This function will have the selected values.

And you can get additional interested functionalities from [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) class

Comment: So if I want to do something with the values - say commit the changes to SharedPreferences - I should do it all in there?

Answer (score 0):

```
hour =timePicker.getCurrentHour();
minute =timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```